# Prevent Mint from suspending while playing music in Spotify

Tags: linux-mint, power-management

In Linux Mint 17 I have `Suspend when inactive for` under `Power Management` set to 10 minutes.

The problem is that the system suspends even when I'm listening to music using [Spotify](https://www.spotify.com/uk/download/previews/).

Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: [This solution](http://superuser.com/a/375235/315715) looks relevant, but the links in the solution are dead at time of writing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found [this article](http://www.maketecheasier.com/prevent-ubuntu-sleep-while-watching-video/) which suggests a couple of ways to stop the screensaver from activating. I have not tested this but since they presumably issue events to stop the activation (the second does at least), that should also count as activity for the inactivity monitor. You'll have to test this though, I'm not sure it will work.

1. Install `caffeine`. This can be done by adding a `ppa` to your system and then installing it like any other package. As long as you're using the normal Mint, this should also work for you.

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install caffeine
   ```

   Then, launch `caffeine` and its icon should appear in your system tray. You can choose which programs should cancel suspending.

   **Note:** As of the [2.7 release of caffeine](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/05/stop-ubuntu-sleeping-caffeine), the program no longer has a GUI and works only as a daemon. When running, it will prevent the screensaver from activating so long as the active window is full screen.
2. The [LightsOn](https://github.com/iye/lightsOn) script. It won't check spotify by default but it is easy enough to modify it to do so. Just add `spotify` to the `delay_progs` array at the beginging of the script:

   ```
   delay_progs=("spotify")
   ```

   Then, add the script to your startup programs so it runs in the background.  and it should stop you from suspending if spotify is running. Note that this does not check whether any music is playing, just whether the program is running.

Let me know if these don't work for the suspension and I'll try and hack something together using `xdotool` or similar programs.

Comment: I've used caffeine and it's worked alright in the past. It seems buggy though since I've had it active and the screensaver would still kick in. Haven't debugged it further, though.

Comment: @slm I haven't so I can't speak as to how well it works. The second solution, the shell script, looks very interesting. It's relatively straightforward and should be easy to expand to blocking suspension.

Comment: yeah I was just giving a recounting of my experience. 2nd solution is prob. A better approach to try.

Comment: The script looks pretty good. Could you add a line to your answer showing how to run the script at start-up?

Comment: @LondonRob that depends on your desktop environment but for most it's something along the lines of settings => startup programs. That's where you can find it on Cinnamon for example. Alternatively, copy the `caffeine.desktop` file from `/usr/share/applications` to `~/.config/autostart/`.

Comment: An obvious negative twist to the LightsOn solution is that I'd normally expect my laptop to sleep when Spotify is not playing music. If I forget to close Spotify (which seems plausible), my laptop will stay on all night!

Answer (score 3):

I just posted an answer for a similar question:
[Linux Mint: How to Avoid Suspending While Music is Playing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340651/linux-mint-how-to-avoid-suspending-while-music-is-playing)

I have written a script to set the suspend timeout to "Never" while pactl detects a running audio source, then reverts the setting when no audio sources are detected.

Here is a copy of the latest answer and script:

I have done a little more work on the above script and it should now work in Cinnamon, Mate and Ubuntu running Gnome. I have tried it out on Live USB versions of Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon and Mate as well as Ubuntu 18.04 - Gnome.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Audiocaffeine

# Works in Linux Mint 19 - Cinnamon, Linux Mint 19 - Mate, Ubuntu 18.04 - Gnome

# Script to temporarily set suspend timout for AC and battery to "Never"
# while audio is playing.  It then reverts the settings when audio is no longer detected.

# Determine if a valid desktop environment is running and exit if it doesn't.
echo "Reported desktop environment: ""$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP"
if [ "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" = "X-Cinnamon" ]; then
    actimeoutid="org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout"
    batttimeoutid="org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout"
    disablevalue=0
elif [ "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" = "MATE" ]; then
    actimeoutid="org.mate.power-manager sleep-computer-ac"
    batttimeoutid="org.mate.power-manager sleep-computer-battery"
    disablevalue=0
elif [ "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" = "ubuntu:GNOME" ]; then
    actimeoutid="org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type"
    batttimeoutid="org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type"
    disablevalue="nothing"
else
    echo "No valid desktop environment is running"
    exit 1
fi

# Create .config directory to store settings if it doesn't exist.
if [ ! -d ~/.config ]; then
    echo ".config directory not found!"
    echo "Creating ~/.config"
    mkdir ~/.config
fi

# Create audiocaffeine directory to store settings if it doesn't exist.
if [ ! -d ~/.config/audiocaffeine ]; then
    echo "Configuration directory not found!"
    echo "Creating ~/.config/audiocaffeine"
    mkdir ~/.config/audiocaffeine
fi

# Restore previous value for AC suspend timeout if script
# was interrupted.
if [ -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend ]; then
    echo "Restoring previous AC suspend timeout."
    read acsuspendtime < ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend
    gsettings set $actimeoutid $acsuspendtime
    echo "Removing temporary file ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend"
    rm ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend
fi

# Restore previous value for battery suspend timeout if script
# was interrupted.
if [ -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend ]; then
    echo "Restoring previous battery suspend timeout."
    read battsuspendtime < ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend
    gsettings set $batttimeoutid $battsuspendtime
    echo "Removing temporary file ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend"
    rm ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend
fi

# Start main loop to check if audio is playing

while true; do

    # Use pactl to detect if there are any running audio sources.
    if pactl list | grep -q "State: RUNNING"; then

        echo "Audio detected."

        # If AC timeout was not previously saved, then save it.
        if [ ! -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend ]; then
            echo "Saving current AC suspend timeout."
            gsettings get $actimeoutid > ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend
        fi

        # If battery timeout was not previously saved, then save it.
        if [ ! -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend ]; then
            echo "Saving current battery suspend timeout."
            gsettings get $batttimeoutid > ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend
        fi

        # Set the suspend timouts to Never using gsettings.
        echo "Changing suspend timeouts."
        gsettings set $actimeoutid $disablevalue
        gsettings set $batttimeoutid $disablevalue

    else
        echo "No audio detected."

        # Restore previous value for AC suspend timeout and delete the
        # temporary file storing it.
        if [ -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend ]; then
            echo "Restoring previous AC suspend timeout."
            read acsuspendtime < ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend
            gsettings set $actimeoutid $acsuspendtime
            echo "Removing temporary file ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend"
            rm ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend
        fi

        # Restore previous value for battery suspend timeout and delete the
        # temporary file storing it.
        if [ -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend ]; then
            echo "Restoring previous battery suspend timeout."
            read battsuspendtime < ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend
            gsettings set $batttimeoutid $battsuspendtime
            echo "Removing temporary file ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend"
            rm ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend
        fi

    fi

    # Pause the script for 60 seconds before doing the loop again.
    sleep 60s

done
```

Answer (score 0):

I added GNOME Flashback support to Jason Gambrel's script. This version also includes his line for ALSA support instead of just PulseAudio. To enable ALSA support you must manually uncomment and comment two lines in the code, identified in the code comments. I could have made it auto detect which is used, but figured that would be wasteful for something that will probably never be changed on most systems and most people use PA or PipeWire with PA emulation today. I can confirm this works on Ubuntu 23.04 in addition to those tested by Jason.

I couldn't add this to the question Jason originally posted this to or as a comment under his script here because of posting restrictions and I'm a newbie to this corner of the Stack Exchange community. If a mod wants to move this and make it a comment under his, I'm more than fine with that.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Audiocaffeine - Pulseaudio
# Original by Jason Gambrel
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340651/linux-mint-how-to-avoid-suspending-while-music-is-playing

# Works in Linux Mint 19 - Cinnamon, Linux Mint 19 - Mate, Ubuntu 18.04-23.04 - Gnome
# Gnome Flashback support added by Joseph Lathem (aka Sienile)

# Script to temporarily set suspend timout for AC and battery to "Never"
# while audio is playing.  It then reverts the settings when audio is no longer detected.

# Determine if a valid desktop environment is running and exit if it doesn't.
echo "Reported desktop environment: ""$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP"
if [ "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" = "X-Cinnamon" ]; then
    actimeoutid="org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout"
    batttimeoutid="org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout"
    disablevalue=0
elif [ "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" = "MATE" ]; then
    actimeoutid="org.mate.power-manager sleep-computer-ac"
    batttimeoutid="org.mate.power-manager sleep-computer-battery"
    disablevalue=0
elif [ "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" = "ubuntu:GNOME" ]; then
    actimeoutid="org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type"
    batttimeoutid="org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type"
    disablevalue="nothing"
elif [ "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" = "GNOME-Flashback:GNOME" ]; then
    actimeoutid="org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type"
    batttimeoutid="org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type"
    disablevalue="nothing"
else
    echo "No valid desktop environment is running"
    exit 1
fi

# Create .config directory to store settings if it doesn't exist.
if [ ! -d ~/.config ]; then
    echo ".config directory not found!"
    echo "Creating ~/.config"
    mkdir ~/.config
fi

# Create audiocaffeine directory to store settings if it doesn't exist.
if [ ! -d ~/.config/audiocaffeine ]; then
    echo "Configuration directory not found!"
    echo "Creating ~/.config/audiocaffeine"
    mkdir ~/.config/audiocaffeine
fi

# Restore previous value for AC suspend timeout if script
# was interrupted.
if [ -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend ]; then
    echo "Restoring previous AC suspend timeout."
    read acsuspendtime < ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend
    gsettings set $actimeoutid $acsuspendtime
    echo "Removing temporary file ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend"
    rm ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend
fi

# Restore previous value for battery suspend timeout if script
# was interrupted.
if [ -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend ]; then
    echo "Restoring previous battery suspend timeout."
    read battsuspendtime < ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend
    gsettings set $batttimeoutid $battsuspendtime
    echo "Removing temporary file ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend"
    rm ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend
fi

# Start main loop to check if audio is playing

while true; do

    # If using ALSA instead of PulseAudio or PipeWire with PA emulation, uncomment the next if statement and comment the one for pactl
    
    # Use ALSA to detect if there are any running audio sources.
    #if grep -q RUNNING /proc/asound/card*/*p/*/status 2>&1; then
    
    # Use pactl to detect if there are any running audio sources.
    if pactl list | grep -q "State: RUNNING"; then

        echo "Audio detected."

        # If AC timeout was not previously saved, then save it.
        if [ ! -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend ]; then
            echo "Saving current AC suspend timeout."
            gsettings get $actimeoutid > ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend
        fi

        # If battery timeout was not previously saved, then save it.
        if [ ! -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend ]; then
            echo "Saving current battery suspend timeout."
            gsettings get $batttimeoutid > ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend
        fi

        # Set the suspend timouts to Never using gsettings.
        echo "Changing suspend timeouts."
        gsettings set $actimeoutid $disablevalue
        gsettings set $batttimeoutid $disablevalue

    else
        echo "No audio detected."

        # Restore previous value for AC suspend timeout and delete the
        # temporary file storing it.
        if [ -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend ]; then
            echo "Restoring previous AC suspend timeout."
            read acsuspendtime < ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend
            gsettings set $actimeoutid $acsuspendtime
            echo "Removing temporary file ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend"
            rm ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend
        fi

        # Restore previous value for battery suspend timeout and delete the
        # temporary file storing it.
        if [ -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend ]; then
            echo "Restoring previous battery suspend timeout."
            read battsuspendtime < ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend
            gsettings set $batttimeoutid $battsuspendtime
            echo "Removing temporary file ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend"
            rm ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend
        fi

    fi

    # Pause the script for 60 seconds before doing the loop again.
    sleep 60s

done
```