# Linux Mint: How to Avoid Suspending While Music is Playing

Tags: linux-mint, audio, power-management, suspend

I have a simple problem: I would like my computer to avoid suspending when music is *playing* on a desktop application on my computer -- I want to do better than a script that keeps my computer awake whenever a music application is *open*. I'm running Linux Mint 18.

I imagine it could work application-by-application, but I also wonder if there is a way to do this by taking advantage of the usual Cinnamon sound applet (or similar). That applet is able to detect and control playback for whatever music applications the user has open -- Spotify, Clementine, Banshee or otherwise. Is there some way a script can determine from either the Sound applet or a specific application whether music is playing?

I am aware of this question: [Prevent Mint from suspending while playing music in Spotify](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159286/prevent-mint-from-suspending-while-playing-music-in-spotify) but the accepted answer does not solve the problem, and caffeine has changed completely since then.

My desired behaviour is beneficial for several reasons:

- If the user leaves a music application open in the background, but with playback halted, the computer will not stay awake indefinitely.
- If the user leaves the computer with music playing, intending the music to carry on, they need not worry about having their music player in fullscreen to keep the music going.
- The user can take advantage of this behaviour in different ways. For example, they could select 20 minutes of relaxing music before bed. When the 20 minute playlist ends, the computer will then suspend for the night. The sleep duration thus automatically adjusts to the length of the playlist.

I'm willing to hack away at this, but I have never written a script for something of this nature and have no idea where to begin. This feels so basic yet useful that perhaps it should be a feature request for Mint.

Comment: It seems like you might be able to detect whether music is playing or not via the daemon that combines the audio from all applications; ex PulseAudio, ALSA's dmix). I'm unfamiliar with the applet you speak of... are you perhaps using PulseAudio?

Comment: Should have been clear, the sound applet is a part of the Cinnamon desktop. Your idea sounds great but like I said, I don't know where to begin in terms of performing that detection. I will try and consult the documentation for the cinnamon sound applet, provided I can find it

Comment: Hi! I'm actually actively writing something to solve this issue. It might be a while until it's done. However, I can give you some pointers to how you might be able to do this: use PulseAudio sink state (`pacmd list-sinks` under state, but I'll use the API). If state is `RUNNING`, then I want to tell logind to inhibit sleep.

Answer (score 2):

I have been struggling with this same thing.  I found a few other posts that talked about using pactl to check on the status of pulseaudio.  Here is one link:

https://superuser.com/questions/393448/detecting-audio-playing-in-a-bash-script

I have tried to put together a very simple script that will change the suspend timeout in Cinnamon's power settings to never temporarily while music is playing and then revert when the music stops.  This is my first real attempt at a script so if you can improve on it feel free.  It will likely only work in Cinnamon though.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Script to temporarily set Cinnamon's suspend timout for AC and battery to "Never"
# while audio is playing.  It then reverts the settings when audio is no longer detected.

# Create directory to store settings if it doesn't exist.
if [ ! -d ~/.config/audiocaffeine ]; then
    echo "Configuration directory not found!"
    echo "Creating ~/.config/audiocaffeine"
    mkdir ~/.config/audiocaffeine
fi

# Restore previous value for AC suspend timeout if script
# was interrupted.
if [ -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend ]; then
    echo "Restoring previous AC suspend timeout."
    read acsuspendtime < ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend
    gsettings set org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout $acsuspendtime
    echo "Removing temporary file ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend"
    rm ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend
fi

# Restore previous value for battery suspend timeout if script
# was interrupted.
if [ -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend ]; then
    echo "Restoring previous battery suspend timeout."
    read battsuspendtime < ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend
    gsettings set org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout $battsuspendtime
    echo "Removing temporary file ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend"
    rm ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend
fi

# Start main loop to check if audio is playing

while true; do

    # Use pactl to detect if there are any running audio sources.
    if pactl list | grep -q RUNNING; then

        echo "Audio detected."

        # If AC timeout was not previously saved, then save it.
        if [ ! -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend ]; then
            echo "Saving current AC suspend timeout."
            gsettings get org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout > ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend
        fi

        # If battery timeout was not previously saved, then save it.
        if [ ! -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend ]; then
            echo "Saving current battery suspend timeout."
            gsettings get org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout > ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend
        fi

        # Set the suspend timouts to Never using gsettings.
        echo "Changing suspend timeouts."
        gsettings set org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 0
        gsettings set org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 0

    else
        echo "No audio detected."

        # Restore previous value for AC suspend timeout and delete the
        # temporary file storing it.
        if [ -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend ]; then
            echo "Restoring previous AC suspend timeout."
            read acsuspendtime < ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend
            gsettings set org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout $acsuspendtime
            echo "Removing temporary file ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend"
            rm ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend
        fi

        # Restore previous value for battery suspend timeout and delete the
        # temporary file storing it.
        if [ -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend ]; then
            echo "Restoring previous battery suspend timeout."
            read battsuspendtime < ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend
            gsettings set org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout $battsuspendtime
            echo "Removing temporary file ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend"
            rm ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend
        fi

    fi

    # Pause the script for 60 seconds before doing the loop again.
    sleep 60s

done
```

Answer (score 2):

I have done a little more work on the above script and it should now work in Cinnamon, Mate and Ubuntu running Gnome. I have tried it out on Live USB versions of Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon and Mate as well as Ubuntu 18.04 - Gnome. I hope this comes in helpful for a few other people.

Jay

```
#!/bin/sh

# Audiocaffeine - Pulseaudio

# Works in Linux Mint 19 - Cinnamon, Linux Mint 19 - Mate, Ubuntu 18.04 - Gnome

# Script to temporarily set suspend timout for AC and battery to "Never"
# while audio is playing.  It then reverts the settings when audio is no longer detected.

# Determine if a valid desktop environment is running and exit if it doesn't.
echo "Reported desktop environment: ""$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP"
if [ "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" = "X-Cinnamon" ]; then
    actimeoutid="org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout"
    batttimeoutid="org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout"
    disablevalue=0
elif [ "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" = "MATE" ]; then
    actimeoutid="org.mate.power-manager sleep-computer-ac"
    batttimeoutid="org.mate.power-manager sleep-computer-battery"
    disablevalue=0
elif [ "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" = "ubuntu:GNOME" ]; then
    actimeoutid="org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type"
    batttimeoutid="org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type"
    disablevalue="nothing"
else
    echo "No valid desktop environment is running"
    exit 1
fi

# Create .config directory to store settings if it doesn't exist.
if [ ! -d ~/.config ]; then
    echo ".config directory not found!"
    echo "Creating ~/.config"
    mkdir ~/.config
fi

# Create audiocaffeine directory to store settings if it doesn't exist.
if [ ! -d ~/.config/audiocaffeine ]; then
    echo "Configuration directory not found!"
    echo "Creating ~/.config/audiocaffeine"
    mkdir ~/.config/audiocaffeine
fi

# Restore previous value for AC suspend timeout if script
# was interrupted.
if [ -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend ]; then
    echo "Restoring previous AC suspend timeout."
    read acsuspendtime < ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend
    gsettings set $actimeoutid $acsuspendtime
    echo "Removing temporary file ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend"
    rm ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend
fi

# Restore previous value for battery suspend timeout if script
# was interrupted.
if [ -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend ]; then
    echo "Restoring previous battery suspend timeout."
    read battsuspendtime < ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend
    gsettings set $batttimeoutid $battsuspendtime
    echo "Removing temporary file ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend"
    rm ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend
fi

# Start main loop to check if audio is playing

while true; do

    # Use pactl to detect if there are any running audio sources.
    if pactl list | grep -q "State: RUNNING"; then

        echo "Audio detected."

        # If AC timeout was not previously saved, then save it.
        if [ ! -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend ]; then
            echo "Saving current AC suspend timeout."
            gsettings get $actimeoutid > ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend
        fi

        # If battery timeout was not previously saved, then save it.
        if [ ! -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend ]; then
            echo "Saving current battery suspend timeout."
            gsettings get $batttimeoutid > ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend
        fi

        # Set the suspend timouts to Never using gsettings.
        echo "Changing suspend timeouts."
        gsettings set $actimeoutid $disablevalue
        gsettings set $batttimeoutid $disablevalue

    else
        echo "No audio detected."

        # Restore previous value for AC suspend timeout and delete the
        # temporary file storing it.
        if [ -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend ]; then
            echo "Restoring previous AC suspend timeout."
            read acsuspendtime < ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend
            gsettings set $actimeoutid $acsuspendtime
            echo "Removing temporary file ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend"
            rm ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend
        fi

        # Restore previous value for battery suspend timeout and delete the
        # temporary file storing it.
        if [ -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend ]; then
            echo "Restoring previous battery suspend timeout."
            read battsuspendtime < ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend
            gsettings set $batttimeoutid $battsuspendtime
            echo "Removing temporary file ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend"
            rm ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend
        fi

    fi

    # Pause the script for 60 seconds before doing the loop again.
    sleep 60s

done
```

Or here is a version that uses ALSA instead of Pulseaudio:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Audiocaffeine - ALSA

# Works in Linux Mint 19 - Cinnamon, Linux Mint 19 - Mate, Ubuntu 18.04 - Gnome

# Script to temporarily set suspend timout for AC and battery to "Never"
# while audio is playing.  It then reverts the settings when audio is no longer detected.

# Determine if a valid desktop environment is running and exit if it doesn't.
echo "Reported desktop environment: ""$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP"
if [ "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" = "X-Cinnamon" ]; then
    actimeoutid="org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout"
    batttimeoutid="org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout"
    disablevalue=0
elif [ "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" = "MATE" ]; then
    actimeoutid="org.mate.power-manager sleep-computer-ac"
    batttimeoutid="org.mate.power-manager sleep-computer-battery"
    disablevalue=0
elif [ "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" = "ubuntu:GNOME" ]; then
    actimeoutid="org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type"
    batttimeoutid="org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type"
    disablevalue="nothing"
else
    echo "No valid desktop environment is running"
    exit 1
fi

# Create .config directory to store settings if it doesn't exist.
if [ ! -d ~/.config ]; then
    echo ".config directory not found!"
    echo "Creating ~/.config"
    mkdir ~/.config
fi

# Create audiocaffeine directory to store settings if it doesn't exist.
if [ ! -d ~/.config/audiocaffeine ]; then
    echo "Configuration directory not found!"
    echo "Creating ~/.config/audiocaffeine"
    mkdir ~/.config/audiocaffeine
fi

# Restore previous value for AC suspend timeout if script
# was interrupted.
if [ -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend ]; then
    echo "Restoring previous AC suspend timeout."
    read acsuspendtime < ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend
    gsettings set $actimeoutid $acsuspendtime
    echo "Removing temporary file ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend"
    rm ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend
fi

# Restore previous value for battery suspend timeout if script
# was interrupted.
if [ -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend ]; then
    echo "Restoring previous battery suspend timeout."
    read battsuspendtime < ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend
    gsettings set $batttimeoutid $battsuspendtime
    echo "Removing temporary file ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend"
    rm ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend
fi

# Start main loop to check if audio is playing

while true; do

    # Use ALSA to detect if there are any running audio sources.
    if grep -q RUNNING /proc/asound/card*/*p/*/status 2>&1; then

        echo "Audio detected."

        # If AC timeout was not previously saved, then save it.
        if [ ! -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend ]; then
            echo "Saving current AC suspend timeout."
            gsettings get $actimeoutid > ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend
        fi

        # If battery timeout was not previously saved, then save it.
        if [ ! -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend ]; then
            echo "Saving current battery suspend timeout."
            gsettings get $batttimeoutid > ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend
        fi

        # Set the suspend timouts to Never using gsettings.
        echo "Changing suspend timeouts."
        gsettings set $actimeoutid $disablevalue
        gsettings set $batttimeoutid $disablevalue

    else
        echo "No audio detected."

        # Restore previous value for AC suspend timeout and delete the
        # temporary file storing it.
        if [ -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend ]; then
            echo "Restoring previous AC suspend timeout."
            read acsuspendtime < ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend
            gsettings set $actimeoutid $acsuspendtime
            echo "Removing temporary file ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend"
            rm ~/.config/audiocaffeine/acsuspend
        fi

        # Restore previous value for battery suspend timeout and delete the
        # temporary file storing it.
        if [ -f ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend ]; then
            echo "Restoring previous battery suspend timeout."
            read battsuspendtime < ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend
            gsettings set $batttimeoutid $battsuspendtime
            echo "Removing temporary file ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend"
            rm ~/.config/audiocaffeine/battsuspend
        fi

    fi

    # Pause the script for 60 seconds before doing the loop again.
    sleep 60s

done
```

Answer (score -1):

Down load and install caffeine app from software manager.  Then install Caffeine Indicator in your desktop panel.  Then  you can choose to activate or deactivate caffeine at your leisure.  Works well for me on Linux Mint MATE 19.3.